# How are real world probability distributions defined?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, exponential-distribution

For example: when trying to find the probability that entering a bank with 3 bank clerks at random will take less than a minute given average times, we use the exponential distribution with $\lambda$.

How exactly is that $\lambda$ found or what is it based on when it comes to real world scenarios?

Answer (score 0):

In the real world, the parameters will usually be approximated emperically. Consider some weird non-fair die, then one can approximate the probabilities by rolling a bunch of times. In your example $\lambda$ is most likely also estimated based on data.

In the real world your mathematical model will rarely be exactly correct. The parameter values will not be exact - in fact, it will probably not even be a true exponential distribution. Instead, we get useful *approximations* to the real world with mathematical models.

Answer (score 0):

This is a great question. First of all, there are infinitely many probability measures given a measurable space $(\Omega,\mathcal{F})$, however, like @Eff said, we usually concern ourselves with an "empirical" or "physical" measure $\mathbb{P}:\mathcal{F} \to [0,1]$ which is constructed from empirical data.

To see how two different probability measures might be used in the real world, let's say we are a market-maker in a fairly liquid options market. Our goal is to earn a profit by buying a given derivative at one price and then to quickly unload that same derivative at a higher price as quickly as possible. The whole point of this trading method is to ideally have *zero* exposure to the directional risk (i.e. the change in the price of the underlying asset) of the option and to have our profit derived completely from the bid-ask spread. To minimize this exposure, we take the empirical probability measure $\mathbb{P}$ and use the Radon-Nikodym theorem to construct an equivalent measure $\mathbb{Q}$ so that the payoff of a certain option, given by a random variable $H_{t}$ can be discounted between a given moment in time (i.e. $t=0$ and a time $T$ by a discount factor $D(0,T)$ via the relationship
$$
H_{0}=D(0,T)\mathbb{E}_{\mathbb{Q}}[H_{T}]
$$
and since $\mathbb{P}$ and $\mathbb{Q}$ are equivalent measures (i.e. they agree on which sets have measure zero/"are impossible"), we can rewrite this as 
$$
H_{0}=D(0,T)\mathbb{E}_{\mathbb{P}}\left[\frac{d\mathbb{Q}}{d\mathbb{P}}H_{T}\right] 
$$
where $\frac{d\mathbb{Q}}{d\mathbb{P}}$ is the Radon-Nikodym derivative of the measure $\mathbb{Q}$ w.r.t. $\mathbb{P}$, which is a function that "re-weights" the empirical measure so as to eliminate the "drift" (or risk) component of the payoff of the option and turns $H_{T}$ into a martingale such that
$$
\mathbb{E}_{\mathbb{Q}}[H_{s}\lvert \{H_{\tau}\lvert\tau<s\}]=H_{s}
$$
which basically means that the expected value of the payoff is constant under the equivalent measure $\mathbb{Q}$.

Now, this is a very simplified version of the theory but it should give you an idea that there are many different probability measures that exist and sometimes more than one that is useful.